# How do I update a sequential attribute with foobar#{n} with n incrementing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-3, auto-increment

I  want to write basically

```
User.find(:all).each {|u| u.update_attribute("email","nil#{incrementing_number}")}
```

How do I make that `#{incrementing_number}` incremement per updated attribute.

:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003137)

```
User.find(:all).each_with_index {|u,i| u.update_attribute("email","nil#{i}")}
```